# what is means of "this.get = function(aUrl, aCallback) {" in js?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, xml, http

I have a code and want to analysis this code:

```
var HttpClient = function() {
    this.get = function(aUrl, aCallback) {
        var anHttpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
        anHttpRequest.onreadystatechange = function() { 
            if (anHttpRequest.readyState == 4 && anHttpRequest.status == 200)
                aCallback(anHttpRequest.responseText);
        }

        anHttpRequest.open( "GET", aUrl, true );            
        anHttpRequest.send( null );
    }
}
```

I can not understand what means of `function(aUrl, aCallback)`? and, aUrl and aCallback inputs not defined? please help me to solve this problem

Answer (score 2):

It's **creating** a function that accepts `aUrl` and `aCallback` as parameters, and assigning that function to the `get` property on `this`. So when `HttpClient` is called, all it does is assign to that `this.get` property. The code within that inner function isn't run until/unless `this.get` is called. Most likely, `HttpClient` is used via `new`, like this:

```
var client = new HttpClient();
```

The code for the function created inside `HttpClient` would be run by doing this:

```
client.get("/some/url", function() {
    // This is the callback
});
```

Here's a simpler example:

```js
function Client() {
    this.get = function(a, b) {
        console.log("a = " + a + ", b = " + b);
    };
}

console.log("Create Client instance:");
var c = new Client();
console.log("Calling c.get():");
c.get(1, 2);
console.log("Calling c.get() again:");
c.get(3, 4);
```